# Toast visible but should not be?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Im starting to get familiar with Bootstrap toasts.  So Im trying to use the following toast markup and have the toast be displayed on a button click

```
    <div class="toast" role="alert" id="toastAlert">
        <div class="toast-header">
            <strong class="mr-auto text-primary">Toast Header</strong>
            <small class="text-muted">5 mins ago</small>
            <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body">
            Some text inside the toast body
        </div>
    </div>
```

Elsewhere, I have a button with a click event, which does the following

```
 $('#toastAlert').toast('show');
```

The problem is that when the page is initially rendered, the toast is visible, when I thought I would only be visible when the toast() method is called.  What am I missing?  Where clicking the button I get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).toast is not a function

Comment: `toast is not a function` means you've no loaded toast / bootstrap... or you've (re-)loaded jquery after ... or you're using a different version of bootstrap that doesn't have toast.

Comment: Yes, You should add `Jquery` library before your jquery code.

Comment: @phong you mean jquery before bootstrap - jquery is loaded otherwise it would be $ is undefined or can't read property toast() of null